# pyspark -- best way to sum values in column of type Array(Integer())

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Lets say this is my dataframe ...

```
name | scores
Dan  |  [10,5,2,12]
Ann  |  [ 12,3,5]
Jon  |  [ ]
```

Desired output is something like

```
name | scores         | Total
Dan  |  [10,5,2,12]   | 29
Ann  |   [ 12,3,5]    | 20
Jon  |  [ ]           | 0
```

I made a UDF along the lines of ....

```
sum_cols = udf(lambda arr: if arr == [] then 0 else __builtins__.sum(arr),IntegerType())

df.withColumn('Total', sum_cols(col('scores'))).show()
```

However, I have learned that UDFs are relatively slow to pure pySpark functions.

Any way to do code above in pySpark without a UDF ?

Comment: Try `sum(explode(scores))`

Comment: that's a good option. I am slightly concerned that with explode, my data-frame will potentially have billions of rows all the sudden if original dataframe is big. Hoping to stay away from that.

Comment: Okay, then use your UDF... The point being is that you have to iterate over that array/column/vector anyway. The explode doesn't modify the original DF. Just expands the array into a column

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a higher-order SQL function [AGGREGATE](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#aggregate) (*reduce* from functional programming), like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.select(
  'name',
  F.expr('AGGREGATE(scores, 0, (acc, x) -> acc + x)').alias('Total')
)
```

First argument is the array column, second is initial value (should be of same type as the values you sum, so you may need to use "0.0" or "DOUBLE(0)" etc if your inputs are not integers) and third argument is a lambda function, which adds each element of the array to an accumulator variable (in the beginning this will be set to the initial value 0).

The transformation will run in a single projection operator, thus will be very efficient. Also you do not need to know the size of the arrays in advance and the array can have different length on each row.

Comment: what if the `x` is a struct, and we need to add a specific column like `x['mount']` ? I got an exception

Comment: @Smaillns: The dot notation works for me, I've just tested: `AGGREGATE(laureates, '', (acc, x) -> CONCAT(acc, ', ', x.firstname))`, where `laureates` is an array of structs and `firstname` is a string structfield in the struct.

Answer (score 9):

for Spark 3.1+, you could simply call [`pyspark.sql.functions.aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.aggregate.html):

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.withColumn(
    "Total",
    F.aggregate("scores", F.lit(0), lambda acc, x: acc + x)
)
```

Notice that you should use `F.lit(0.0)` if the column type is not integer.

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't know the length of the array (as in your example):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
psaudo_counts = df.select('name').distinct().withColumn('score', F.lit(0))
df = df.select('name', F.explode('scores').alias('score')).unionByName(psaudo_counts)
df = df.groupby('name').agg(F.sum('name').alias('Total'))
```

In case you do know the length of the array:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
length_of_array = 3
df = df.select('name', sum([F.col('scores').getItem(i) for i in range(length_of_array)]).alias('Total'))
```

Thanks for cricket_007 for the tip and this [old mail](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201608.mbox/%3CCAJE05O6ftqBo7Xfyg_ycDFZd26dMukrVh-hJ-eA1GAZsdtXi2g@mail.gmail.com%3E) for the fixed length idea

Answer (score 3):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.select(
  'name',
  F.expr('AGGREGATE(scores,cast(0 as float), (acc, x) -> acc + x)').alias('Total')
)
```

You won't get error only If you use cast(0 as 'datatype') in aggregate function.

Answer (score 3):

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('Dan', [10, 5, 2, 12]), 
        ('Ann', [12, 3, 5]),
        ('Jon', [])
    ],
    ['name', 'scores'])

data.show()

+----+--------------+
|name|        scores|
+----+--------------+
| Dan|[10, 5, 2, 12]|
| Ann|    [12, 3, 5]|
| Jon|            []|
+----+--------------+
```

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

udf_function = udf(lambda x: int(np.array(x, dtype=int).sum()), IntegerType())
data = data.withColumn('sum', udf_function('scores'))
data.show()

+----+--------------+---+
|name|        scores|sum|
+----+--------------+---+
| Dan|[10, 5, 2, 12]| 29|
| Ann|    [12, 3, 5]| 20|
| Jon|            []|  0|
+----+--------------+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a simpler formulation/implementation with the withColumn method :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.withColumn('Total',F.expr('AGGREGATE(scores, 0, (acc, x) -> acc + x)'))
```